# linux: how can i open a gui program like google-chrome from the command line so that it stays open even after teminal closes

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, chrome

i am a ubuntu user. 
i often open/launch programms from the command line / terminal.
But when i close the terminal, the program also shuts down.
Is there some way to let the programs stay open, even when the terminal, i launched it from, is closed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nohup`:

```
$ nohup <command>
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

From `man nohup`: "run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty". Redirect standard output to `/dev/null` to avoid creating `nohup.out`.

I guess you can also use `<command> & exit`, but that will close the terminal immediately.